# Convert the text of a string to a variable name?

Tags: swift, function, sprite-kit

I tried to explain this in a previous question but failed...

```
func setPiece(square: String, piece: String) {

   if (piece == "whiteKing") {A1Square.texture = whiteKing}

}
```

This works great, but the problem is I am going to need a lot of code for all the squares and pieces, what I want to so is this...

```
  func setPiece(square: String, piece: String) {

       if (piece == "whiteKing") {square.texture = whiteKing}

    }
```

Where "A1Square" is being passed into the function...

I want to transform the String "A1Square".texture = whiteKing into A1Square.texture = whiteKing.  Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Not sure about what programming language that is, but have you tried telling the function that you are actually passing an object of class `A1Aquare` instead of a `String`? I mean, the function signature says it receives two strings instead of a `A1Square` and a `String`, but it seems to me like you want an object of a different class as first parameter.

Comment: @Azurlake OP's question is in Swift, as you can see *in the tags*. :) And I think OP wants to transform the string (name) into an object variable using this name (like you can do in Ruby with interpolation).

Comment: @EricD. Thanks Eric D., ok I'll reformulate my answer: _Not sure how this will be in Swift since I am not a Swift programmer_, but (...) ; ) Cheers

Comment: @Azurlake I meant no offense of course, it was just a note. :)

Comment: @EricD. Didn't feel offended ; ) don't worry. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azurlake had the right idea, try passing into the function an object of class `A1Square` instead of `String`.

If you don't want to do this, and if `A1Square` is a node, you can use the SpriteKit method `childNodeWithName:`. If you call this on the square's parent node and use the string for the square's name, it will return the child node for that name.

For instance, if you added the square to `self` you could say:

```
let node: SKSpriteNode = self.childNodeWithName(square) as SKSpriteNode
if (piece == "whiteKing") {node.texture = whiteKing}
```

Comment: Yeah I just needed to pass the SkSpriteNode!!  Yeah thanks guys.  Not quite sure why I didn't think of that...  For some reason I just thought of passing only integers and strings.